# Type errors in simple Haskell AST

Tags: haskell, abstract-syntax-tree

(Please forgive me in advance for any formatting errors, as this is the first time I've asked a question here.)

I'm working on an interpreter for the While language for class, and I think I have a pretty good handle on the ideas behind it and what I need to do.  Some code was provided for us (the eval functions for the Expr type) and we have to implement the eval for the Statement type and the symbol lookup functionality for assignments.

My current problem is that I'm getting type errors while trying to do the above and I'm not sure why.

Here's the relevant code (note that the While eval is set to = 0 intentionally at the moment):

```
data Expr = Num Integer
      | Var String
      | Bin Op Expr Expr deriving Show

data Statement = Assign String Expr
                | If Expr Statement Statement
                | While Expr Statement
                | Compound [Statement] deriving Show

env = [("n",1), ("fact", 1)]

eval (Num x) _ = x
eval (Var v) e = xlookup v e
   where xlookup v ((w, x):r) | v==w = x
                              | otherwise = xlookup v r
eval (Bin op l r) e = kop op (eval l e) (eval r e)
  where kop Mul x y = x * y
        kop Sub x y = x - y
        kop Add x y = x + y
        kop Gt  x y | x > y = 1
                    | otherwise = 0

eval (While exp s) e = 0

factorial = (Compound [
               (Assign "n" (Num 7)),
               (Assign "fact" (Num 1)),
               (While (Bin Gt (Var "n") (Num 1))
                  (Compound [
                      (Assign "fact" (Bin Mul (Var "fact") (Var "n"))),
                      (Assign "n" (Bin Sub (Var "n") (Num 1)))
                  ])
               )
            ])
```

Here's what I get:

```
Hugs> :l while.hs
ERROR "while.hs":37 - Type error in function binding
*** Term           : eval
*** Type           : Statement -> [([Char],Integer)] -> Integer
*** Does not match : Expr -> [([Char],Integer)] -> Integer
```

Basically, every attempt I make at an eval function for a Statement, Haskell seems to be expecting an Expr instead and I'm not sure why.  I'm sure this is a very basic question but unfortunately I'm very new to Haskell and apparently still pretty terrible at it.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You either need to make `eval` a method of a typeclass, which I think is overkill at this point, or make separate eval functions for your Expr and Statement types:

```
eval_expr (Num x) = ...
eval_expr (Var x) = ...
eval_expr (Bin op l r) = ...

eval_stmt (While expr x) = ...
```

The typeclass method would look like:

```
class Eval a where
    eval :: a -> [([Char], Integer)] -> Integer

instance Eval Expr where
    eval (Num x) = ...
    ...

instance Eval Statement where
    eval (While expr x) = ...
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful.  I made some assumptions about function overloading that were apparently not accurate!  I think either way will work in this case, so I'll think on it some more.

Answer (score 3):

The first three equations for `eval` take an `Expr` and an environment, but `While` is a constructor of the type `Statement`. So the definitions you give are incompatibly typed. You will probably need two evaluation functions, one for expressions and one for statements. If you give your definitions type signatures, you will get better (as in: easier to understand) error messages in general.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful.  I didn't know how to give eval a type signature due to the different types I was trying to pass it; in retrospect, that probably should have been a clue.